# How can I make invisible an "Edit Text"? [MATLAB]

Tags: matlab, user-interface, visibility

I have a Text Edit with name "desv" and I want to make it invisible.
I am doing this

```
set(handles.desv,'HandleVisibility','off');
```

but it doesn´t work.
Any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, i modified the field Visible:

```
set(handles.desv,'Visible','Off');
```

Comment: Glad you found the answer! It would be good if you also explain what is the difference between them and why this is the correct one.

Comment: If I understood correctly, HandleVisibility is for the access to a property. And Visibility is only for the graphical representation of the object. You can also see this video, where the man explains the HandleVisibility http://es.mathworks.com/videos/handlevisibility-property-to-make-guis-visible-in-handles-hierarchy-97278.html

Comment: Yeah, I know. I mean add that to your answer.